How fast does the number of "fixed" points grow compared the the size of the ball in the following group?
Let $M = \oplus_{i\in \mathbb Z}  V^{(i)}$ where each $ V^{(i)} \cong \mathbb Z ^5 $. Let $e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4, e_5$ be the standard basis of $\mathbb Z^5$.  Let $e_j^{(i)}$ be the element  in $M$ whose $i$-th coordinate is $e_j$ and other coordinates are $0$.
Consider the following subgroup $
N = \left\{\begin{array}{c|c}
 e_1^{(i)}-e_1^{(i+1)} & \\
e_2^{(i)}-e_4^{(i+1)} & i \in \mathbb{Z}\\
e_3^{(i)}-e_5^{(i+1)} &  \\
e_3^{(i)}+e_4^{(i)}+e_5^{(i)}+e_1^{(i)}-e_2^{(i+1)} &
\end{array}\right\}.
$
Let $K = M/N$  and $G = K\rtimes_\phi \mathbb{Z}$  where $\phi(1)$ shifts coordinate one place to the right in $K$. Let $F = \langle  e_1^{(i)}  \mid i \in \mathbb{Z}  \rangle$ be the set of fixed points of $\phi$, this is a normal subgroup of $G$.
Let $T =  \{ e_i^{(0)}  \mid 1 \leq i \leq 5  \} $ be a finite subset of $K$ and   $S = T \cup \{ (0,1) \}$ be the natural generating set of $G$.
Question:  Can we show that $  \lim _{r \rightarrow \infty}  |S^r \cap F| / |S^r| = 0$?  (It is clear that $|S^r|$ grows exponentially)
This is an attempt to answer this question. I find it a bit tricky to determine the growth of $|S^r \cap F|$ because $F$ is not a direct summand of $K$.
Any ideas would be much appreciated! Thank you for reading.

What is $S^r{}$?

Thanks for reading @JyrkiLahtonen.  We denote by $S^n$ the $n$-fold product set $\left{s_1 \cdot \ldots \cdot s_n ; s_i \in S\right}$. This is the ball of radius $n$ in the Cayley graph of $G$ relative to $S$.

Also posted to Overflow, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/474408/how-fast-does-the-number-of-fixed-points-grow-compared-to-the-size-of-the-ball
